# How to create web deployment package in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment-project

I am now using the Visual Studio 2013, where I want to create a web deployment installer for project like I am doing in Visual Studio 2008.

But I am not getting any option inside **Setup and Deployment**. Can anybody please guide me how to create the installer package for web application? I have publish folder ready with me. Can I create any installer from VS2008 using this Publish folder?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio no longer includes a setup installer out of the box.  This was removed in VS2012; the guidance instead is to use a 3rd party option like WiX or InstallShield.

Another option, if you don't need to use an MSI based installer, is to use [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).  A web project in VS can create a [deployment package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can then be published to any number of websites at any time.  It can also be customized by configuring parameters and setting their values at deploy time ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  Web Deploy packages can support deploying your web content, IIS settings, and database.

Answer (score 3):

VS2013 will support it again. It will be released in the next update patch of the VS2013.
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/18/microsoft-reinstalls-visual-studio-installer.aspx